# Como fazer com que dois arquivos html funcionem com o mesmo javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para que eu clique em um botao em uma pagina html, e na outra pagina html apareça alguma coisa com um unico arquivo javascript?

exemplo abaixo:

HTML 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Teste</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="adicionar()">Teste</button>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

HTML 2

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Teste</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="teste"></div>

    <script src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var ad = document.getElementById("teste")

function teste(){
    ad.innerHTML += "Teste"
}

function adicionar(){
    function teste()
}
```

nisso eu queria que, cada vez que eu clicasse no botao de uma pagina html, aparecesse "teste" na outra pagina html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da maneira que explicou você explicou, eu vejo duas formas de fazer o que precisa. LocalStorage e WebSocket

Localstorage

```
function adicionar(){

  var element = document.getElementById('teste')

  if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null){
    ad.innerHTML += localStorage.getItem('texto');
  }else{
    localStorage.setItem('texto', 'texto que quero printar');
  }

}
```

Para usar o websocket vai precisar de uma bibliotecas de terceiros (subir um servidor de websocket).

Comment: vou entar aqui, vlw mano